# Variable determines value to cell but calls custom function and executes after

Tags: excel, vba, loops

**The purpose of the code**

My sheet is an overview of agreements. The first sheet is the overview, and the every agreement has a sheet for itself. Which is why i does not loop through the first sheet. Whenever it finds the end date of the agreement is prior to the date of today, then it shall renew the end date year according to the agreement automatic extension.

**Problem**

I have a problem, where my sheet is required to update a date string, but whenever it does so, it somehow calls my custom function, that has nothing to do with it. After having called the custom function, it executes and it has updated the value. Whenever it jumps into my function which is:

```
    Function NxtShtNm(number As Long) As String
    Application.Volatile True
    NxtShtNm = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Index + number - 1).Name
    End Function
```

it destroys the formula in my cell. This formula has been used to hyperlink to the different sheets from the overview sheet.

**Values**

LnLVal is 10-11-2018
NtceVal is 8 months
AutoExtVal is 5 years

```
Sub Message()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim c As Range
Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim OblLeftLR As String, NtceLR As String
Set sht = Sheets(1)
Set Wf = WorksheetFunction
Dim vR() As Variant
Dim k As Long, j As Integer

OblLeft = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Obligation left").Address(False, False, xlA1)
OblLeftSub = sht.Range(OblLeft).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(OblLeft, "1", "")
OblLeftOff = sht.Range(OblLeft).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)
OblLR = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, OblLeftSub).End(xlUp).Row
rngOblLeft = OblLeftOff & ":" & OblLeftSub & OblLR
rngOblMinus = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(rngOblLeft), "")
rngObl = OblLeftOff & ":" & OblLeftSub & OblLR - rngOblMinus

Ntce = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Notice").Address(False, False, xlA1)
NtceSub = sht.Range(Ntce).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(Ntce, "1", "")
NtceOff = sht.Range(Ntce).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)
NtceLR = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, NtceSub).End(xlUp).Row
rngNtce2 = NtceOff & ":" & NtceSub & NtceLR
rngNtceMinus = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(rngNtce2), "")
rngNtce = NtceOff & ":" & NtceSub & NtceLR - rngNtceMinus

StreNme = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Store").Address(False, False, xlA1)
StreNmeSub = sht.Range(StreNme).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(StreNme, "1", "")
StreNmeOff = sht.Range(StreNme).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)
StreNmeVal2 = ""

AutoExt = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Automatical extension of contract").Address(False, False, xlA1)
AutoExtSub = sht.Range(AutoExt).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(AutoExt, "1", "")

LnL = sht.Range("1:1").Find("Lease end lessee").Address(False, False, xlA1)
LnLSub = sht.Range(LnL).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(LnL, "1", "")

MyDate = Date

On Error Resume Next

For Each c In Range(rngObl).Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        CValue = c.Value
        CAddress = c.Address(False, False, xlA1)
        NtceAddress = sht.Range(CAddress).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CAddress, OblLeftSub, NtceSub)
        NtceValue = sht.Range(NtceAddress).Value
        NtceVal = Left(NtceValue, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", NtceValue) - 1)
        CVal = Left(CValue, WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", CValue) - 1)
        Rslt = CVal - NtceVal
            If Rslt <= 3 Then
                StreNmeAddress = sht.Range(CAddress).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CAddress, OblLeftSub, StreNmeSub)
                StreNmeVal = sht.Range(StreNmeAddress).Value
                AutoExtAddress = sht.Range(CAddress).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CAddress, OblLeftSub, AutoExtSub)
                AutoExtVal = sht.Range(AutoExtAddress).Value
                RsltMsg = Rslt & " month(s) - "
                    If Rslt = 0 Then
                        LnLAddress = sht.Range(CAddress).Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(CAddress, OblLeftSub, LnLSub)
                        LnLVal = sht.Range(LnLAddress).Value
                        Rslt = DateDiff("d", MyDate, LnLVal) - 365
                        RsltMsg = Rslt & " days - "
                            If Rslt = 1 Then
                                RsltMsg = Rslt & " day - "
                            End If
                    End If
                    If Rslt = 1 Then
                        RsltMsg = Rslt & " month - "
                    End If
                Msg = StreNmeVal2 & vbNewLine & StreNmeVal & " will renew in " & RsltMsg & AutoExtVal
            End If
        StreNmeVal2 = Msg
    End If
Next

On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "The rent agreements for the following stores will automatically renew its period, within the next 3 months:" & vbNewLine & Msg

End Sub

Sub UpdateSheets()
Dim WS_count As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim sht As Worksheet

Today = Date

WS_count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

For I = 1 To WS_count
    If I = 1 Then
        Else
        Set sht = Sheets(I)
            LnLAddress = sht.Range("A:A").Find("Lease end lessee:", , LookIn:=xlValues).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            LnLOff = sht.Range(LnLAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            LnLVal = sht.Range(LnLOff).Value
            NtceAddress = sht.Range("A:A").Find("Notice:", , LookIn:=xlValues).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            NtceOff = sht.Range(NtceAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
            NtceVal = sht.Range(NtceOff).Value
            On Error GoTo Ending:
            NtceVal = Left(NtceVal, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", NtceVal) - 1)
            LnLVal = DateSerial(Year(LnLVal), Month(LnLVal) - NtceVal, Day(LnLVal))
            LnLYear = Year(LnLVal)
            On Error GoTo 0
                If LnLYear <= Year(Today) Then
                    LnLMonth = Month(LnLVal)
                        If LnLMonth <= Month(Today) Then
                            LnLDay = Day(LnLVal)
                                If LnL < Day(Today) Then
                                AutoExtAddress = sht.Range("A:A").Find("Automatical extension of contract", , LookIn:=xlValues).Address(False, False, xlA1)
                                AutoExtOff = sht.Range(AutoExtAddress).Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False, xlA1)
                                AutoExtVal = sht.Range(AutoExtOff).Value
                                AutoExt = Left(AutoExtVal, Application.WorksheetFunction.Find(" ", AutoExtVal) - 1)
                                LnLNewVal = DateSerial(Year(LnLVal) + AutoExt, Month(LnLVal) + NtceVal, Day(LnLVal))
                                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                                sht.Range(LnLOff).Value = LnLNewVal
                                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                                End If
                        End If
                End If
    End If
Ending:
On Error GoTo 0
Next I

End Sub
```

**Goal**

I want my macro not to jump into my Module with the abovementioned function.
I have already tried to use:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

But this hasn't helped, it just delayed jumping into the module until xlCalculationAutomatic.

Thank you for your help in advance :)

Comment: Set “Application.Volatile False” in your function and avoid it being called at every sheet calculation

Comment: Okay, I’ll try that :)

Comment: Now that I've tried that, this works really well… Problem now is that my function doesn't update, unless I "F2" and enter... Is there any way I can make the code update itself again?

Comment: Or Is there a better solution to my problem, whereas I don't have to change "Application.Volatile True" to "False"?